# Pass data from view to view and display in view laravel?

Tags: laravel

In ***Controller*** :

```
$data = [
  'name' => 'Jony',
  'age'. => 18
];
return View::make("user/detail", compact('data'));
```

In ***view/user/detail.blade.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-EN">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>Details</h1>
   <div class="user-informatio">
       //
       I want to display view : user.blade.php
       //
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

In **view/user/user.blade.php**

```
<div>{{ $data['name'] }}</div> <br/>
<div>{{ $data['age'] }}</div>
```

I want to pass `$data` from `detail.blade.php` to `user.blade.php` and display `user.blade` form inside `detail.blade`.
Please give me any ideas.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `@include` user.blade.php file in it.

```
<div class="user-informatio">
   //
   I want to display view : user.blade.php
   //
   @include('user.user', $data)
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer helped me.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
return view('user/detail')->with('data', $data);
```

then in the view just use $data